# env command shows 3 times same path

Tags: command-line, osx-lion, path, environment-variables

When i run `env` it shows 3 times `/usr/bin` under PATH . Same for every path under  `PATH` title. 
For example - my scala bin directory shows 3 times . 
However, in my .bash_profile, it is written just one time . Also its not in .bashrc also. I need to make this 3 occurrences to 1, as even though I remove some path under PATH in .bash_profile, it still shows 2 times , which means that path is still set.
 `echo $PATH` shows the same thing.  
And , if it matters I am using macosx.

Answer (score 0):

OK..So I found the solution. 
Here is what I was doing :-
 1) `vi ~/.bash_profile`
 2) make changes
3) `source ~/.bash_profile` to see those changes in effect . 
It seems for every editing and subsequent source command, temporarily keeps in current session.
 So , if i made changes 3 times and consequent `source` command, it shows 3 times the same path if i do `echo $PATH` or `env`.
Closing the terminal and restarting it puts back everything to normal. 
So, it was just a matter or restarting the terminal!! 
Clarification :- Different platforms may perform differently. I found macosx-10.7 works this way.